# How to join this Sql statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have some separately `Select` statement in `SQL` as follows:

```
Select HiveNumber, HiveRace, QueenAge, HiveType From tHives
```

and

```
Select HiveNumber, SUM(FeedingAmount) AS TotalFeeding From tHivesFeeding
Group By HiveNumber
```

and

```
Select HiveNumber, HoneyStatus, EggLayingStatus, Body, Comb, VisitDetails 
From  tHivesDetails 
Where VisitDate in (Select MAX(VisitDate) From tHivesDetails)
order by HiveNumber
```

and

```
Select HiveNumber, SUM(HoneyComb) AS TotalCombs From tHoneyHarvest
Group By HiveNumber
```

and

```
Select HiveNumber, SUM(WaxNumber) AS TotalWax From tHivesDetails
Group By HiveNumber
```

Now my question is how can i combined these statement into on sql statement and ordered them by HiveNumber

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Ok, But all of them get same rows and has aggregated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a number of left joins, and a [**`outer apply()`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx) for the latest `visitdate` from `tHivesDetails`:

If there will always be corresponding rows to join on, you can switch these `left join`s to `inner join`s and the `outer apply()` to `cross apply()`.

```
select 
    h.HiveNumber, h.HiveRace, h.QueenAge, h.HiveType 
  , hd.HoneyStatus, hd.EggLayingStatus, hd.Body, hd.Comb, hd.VisitDetails
  , hf.TotalFeeding
  , hh.TotalCombs
  , hdw.TotalWax
from tHives h
  left join (
    select 
        HiveNumber
      , TotalCombs = sum(HoneyComb)
    from tHoneyHarvest 
    group by HiveNumber
    ) as hh on h.HiveNumber = hh.HiveNumber
  left join (
    select 
        HiveNumber
      , TotalFeeding = sum(FeedingAmount)
    from tHivesFeeding
    group By HiveNumber    
    ) as hf
      on h.HiveNumber = hf.HiveNumber
  left join (
    select 
        HiveNumber
      , TotalWax = sum(waxNumber)
    from tHivesDetails
    group by HiveNumber
    ) as hdw 
      on h.HiveNumber = hdw.HiveNumber
  outer apply ( /* cross apply to get latest Visit Date details */
    select top 1
      hd.HoneyStatus, hd.EggLayingStatus, hd.Body, hd.Comb, hd.VisitDetails
    from tHivesDetails hd
    where h.HiveNumber = hd.HiveNumber
    order by hd.VisitDate desc
    ) as hd
```

Comment: i really appreciated that you spend time for writing this
here an error i get:
>>The multi-part identifier "hh.HoneComb" could not be bound.

Comment: @SaraniO Oops, remove the `hh.` in `sum(hh.HoneComb)`, and correct for my typo in `HoneyComb`, which becomes `, TotalCombs = sum(HoneyComb)`

Comment: tanks a lot, also need a 's' in `from tHivesDetails` in line 4 from the last
OMG that all I needed
let me double check the answer and accepted that :)

Comment: @SaraniO I can't find the missing `s`, but happy to have helped!

Comment: in line 4 from the last it should be tHivesDetails instead of tHiveDetails

Comment: @SaraniO Ohh! Gotcha

Comment: another question is what if want to get these select between 2 date?
I have to add date as parameters after each `select` statement?

Comment: @SaraniO That would probably be better as a new question, and when you ask include all of your table schemas for the query (full column lists).

Comment: Ok I try myself and if couldn't find a solution ask it as a question tnx

Answer (score 2):

You would use `left join` and a bunch of subqueries.  Here is an idea of how this works:

```
Select h.HiveNumber, h.HiveRace, h.QueenAge, h.HiveType,
       hf.TotalFeeding, . . .
From Hives h left join
     (Select HiveNumber, SUM(FeedingAmount) AS TotalFeeding
      From tHivesFeeding
      Group By HiveNumber   
    ) hf
    on h.HiveNumber = hf.HiveNumber left join
    . . .
```